# ClassNotFound exception after git pull IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, git, gitlab, runtime-error

Me and a fellow student have to develop an application in **Java**. We are using the **Spring Boot** framework with **Gradle** configurations. For version control, we're using **Gitlab**, everything was going well and we already have some features done but unfortunately I'm having problems with updating my project.

When I pull from the repo, my project won't start up anymore as it can't find/load the `main` class due to a `ClassNotFoundException`.

**Error output:**

[image]

Hopefully someone can help with this problem, i'd really appreciate it!

Kind regards :)

Comment: try `./gradlew clean build` in the root directory of your project

Comment: i'll try, i'll let you know in a couple of minutes

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải now i get this output '
Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved '

Comment: try this: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: @zabaykal is there a way to solve the problem i have? instead of re-indexing everything? I just want to pull and push without worrying about re-indexing my whole project everytime

Comment: @zabaykal this did not solve anything, i got the same error as the one in my original post.

Comment: is it possible to let me see your project?

Comment: @ToànNguyễnHải yea sure, i think? can you add me on discord and we'll call later as i'm in a class right now

Comment: ok, email me toannh0401@gmail.com, I'm available from 8 pm-0 am GMT+7